# Sequence of functions that converges in L∞ but not L2?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence

Can someone give me an example of a sequence $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ of (preferably continuous) functions from any subset of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ that converges to a function in the $L^∞$ sense but not in the $L^2$ sense? That is, as $k \rightarrow \infty$, there exists an $f$ such that

$$
\sup_{x \in \mathrm{dom} (f)} |f(x) - f_k(x)| \rightarrow 0,
$$

but no $g$ such that

$$
\int_{\mathrm{dom} (g)} (g(x) - f_k(x))^2\mathop{dx} \rightarrow 0.
$$

This is probably very easy, but I can't find any examples after *lots* of searching. Most resources say that $L^\infty$ convergence implies $L^2$ convergence in finite measure spaces, but they don't provide an example of it *not* applying in other spaces.

Edit: Ah, whoops, I swapped around $L^\infty$ and $L^2$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is any non-zero continuous function such that $\int |f(x)|^{2}dx<\infty$ then $(f(nx)) \to 0$ in $L^{2}$ but not in $L^{\infty}$.

Note that $\int |f(nx)|^{2}dx=\frac  1n \int |f(y)|^{2} dy \to 0$.

EDIT: For the revised version take $f_n(x)=\frac  1 {\sqrt n} I_{(0,n)}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in $L^{\infty}$ but $\int |f_n|^{2}=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I don't think continuity is important here.

Comment: @KeeferRowan OP said 'preferably continuous'.

Comment: So sorry, I swapped around $L^\infty$ and $L^2$.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't your edited example *also* a sequence that converges in $L^2$ but not $L^\infty$, as opposed to the other way around?

Comment: @Shien Sorry, I have now edited the answer.